# Не могу запустить тест JUnit 5

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit

Написал простой тест (первый в моей жизни), в результате запуска падает с ошибками

```
org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Could not load class with name: admin.interactor.device.list.DeviceListInteractorTest
    at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.lambda$getJavaClass$0(ClassSelector.java:73)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.getJavaClass(ClassSelector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.lambda$resolve$3(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:69)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1251)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolve(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:68)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolveSelectors(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:50)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:61)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:130)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:117)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:82)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:48)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)

июн 25, 2018 9:53:16 AM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Could not load class with name: admin.interactor.device.list.DeviceListInteractorTest
    at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.lambda$getJavaClass$0(ClassSelector.java:73)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.getJavaClass(ClassSelector.java:72)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1376)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.resolve(ClassSelectorResolver.java:29)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.VintageDiscoverer.collectTestClasses(VintageDiscoverer.java:64)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.VintageDiscoverer.discover(VintageDiscoverer.java:51)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.discover(VintageTestEngine.java:61)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:130)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:117)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:82)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:48)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)

июн 25, 2018 9:53:16 AM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Could not load class with name: admin.interactor.device.list.DeviceListInteractorTest
    at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.lambda$getJavaClass$0(ClassSelector.java:73)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.getJavaClass(ClassSelector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.lambda$resolve$3(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:69)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1251)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolve(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:68)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolveSelectors(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:50)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:61)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:130)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:117)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:65)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)

июн 25, 2018 9:53:16 AM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Could not load class with name: admin.interactor.device.list.DeviceListInteractorTest
    at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.lambda$getJavaClass$0(ClassSelector.java:73)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.getJavaClass(ClassSelector.java:72)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1376)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.resolve(ClassSelectorResolver.java:29)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.VintageDiscoverer.collectTestClasses(VintageDiscoverer.java:64)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.VintageDiscoverer.discover(VintageDiscoverer.java:51)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.discover(VintageTestEngine.java:61)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:130)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:117)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:65)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

Gradle

```
testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:$junitVersion"
testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junitVersion"

testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:4.12.0"
testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junitVersion"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начиная с версии Gradle 4.7 у меня такие зависимости для JUnit5:

```
    dependencies {
        testCompile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:$junitVersion'
        testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junitVersion'
        testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junitVersion'
    }
    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
```

И убедиться, что для аннотации @Test правильный импорт:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

Comment: И не забыть все это завернуть в task {} в корне build.gradle